# How to parse JSON of String Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have ajax code which returns JSON data which is just Array of string(no key/val pair).

```
function loadData() {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: apiURL,
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 2000,
    success: onLoadData
};

function onLoadData(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var arr = JSON.parse(data);
    //var arr = jQuery.parseJSON(data); this also fails.
    alert(arr[0]);
};
```

Output of `console.log()` is `= ["one", "two", "three"]` but `JSON.parse()` gives error as :

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

I checked JSON using [validator](https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=75adcd93ec75683811790b1bc6a38435) which says this is valid JSON.
Can someone help to understand why `parse()` is failing?

Comment: It's an array already, you cannot `JSON.parse()` an array. If you specify `dataType: "json"` jquery parses it for you.

Comment: Setting your `dataType` to `json` automatically parses the response as `json`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `remove JSON.parse(data)` if its already an array. You'll see that your `alert` call should work fine.

Comment: The reason WHY this works is in the [documentation of jQuery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).  `The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter...`.  The dataType states `If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object,...`.  So jQuery by default usually decodes a JSON string into a Javascript Object.

Comment: thanks @ErikPhilips for details. Yes I found that parse() needs https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse parameter of type string and because typeof(data) is object, using var string_data = JSON.stringify(data); solves the issue so as said in above answers "data" is alerady array it need not to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
alert(data[0]) // and remove everything else in that callback.
```

You're already fine with that `dataType : "json"`.